# How to set image alignment on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've successfully set text alignments on Flutter

[image]

by wrapping it in Column, use CrossAxisAlignment.stretch and textAlign.left.

As you see, **Tsing Yi** and **0.4 KM** are left-aligned, for example.

Now, how to do the same thing to those logos?

Relevant code:

```
              Expanded(
                              child:Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 6.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                              padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 6.0),
                                              child: Image.asset("assets/images/"+ _displayedList[position].brand+".jpg", height: 40, width: 40)
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _displayedList[position].location,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _displayedList[position].distance.toString()+" KM",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0), textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ), flex: 3,
                            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first `Column` set the `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`.

However, I don’t quite get why you’re practically wrapping every widget in a `Column` when it only has on child. There are better options for such layout, you should be fine with one `Column` only and playing with spacing.